# SQL query for selecting specific date range (such as the current month only)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am working in SQL Server 2012.

I am trying to collect all data for the current month (2015-07) and group them.  When I run this query it selects only the current day.

```
SELECT
    YEAR, MONTH, IDWHSE, IDLOCATION, IDCUST, 
    SUM(PALLETDAYS) AS PALLETDAYS, 
    COUNT(*) AS LOCATIONDAYS
FROM 
    [METRICS].[dbo].[DailyData]
WHERE
    DATE = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MM, 0, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY 
    YEAR, MONTH, IDWHSE, IDLOCATION, IDCUST, PALLETDAYS
```

Thanks in advance

Gerry

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    YEAR, MONTH, IDWHSE, IDLOCATION, IDCUST, 
    SUM(PALLETDAYS) AS PALLETDAYS, 
    COUNT(*) AS LOCATIONDAYS
FROM 
    [METRICS].[dbo].[DailyData]
WHERE
    MONTH(DATE) = MONTH(SYSDATETIME())
GROUP BY 
    YEAR, MONTH, IDWHSE, IDLOCATION, IDCUST, PALLETDAYS
```

By using the `MONTH()` function, you get the month number - both of your column `Date` (which is a really horribly bad name for a column, since `DATE` is also a reserved keyword for a datatype in SQL Server 2012 - try to use something more meaningful than just `Date`!) and the current date (I prefer the `SYSDATETIME()` function over `GETDATE()`)

Comment: Thanks for your help and yes I'll change the date column name.